# How to cast a Session object to Map?

Tags: java, session, generics, dictionary, casting

I am converting old java code to support generics and came across this line of code which was trying to cast an object retrieved from the session into a `TreeMap`:

```
TreeMap allTransactions = (TreeMap) pageContext.getSession()
                                               .getAttribute("allTransactions");
```

When I tried to convert it to specific type:

```
TreeMap<String, MyDataBean> allTransactions = (TreeMap<String, MyDataBean>) 
                       pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("allTransactions");
```

It gave me a `warning`:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to TreeMap<String,MyDataBean>
```

In an effort to get rid of the warning completely, I wrote a method to cast it to `Map`:

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> castToMap(Class<? extends K> clazz1, 
                                       Class<? extends V> clazz2, Map<?,?> c) {
    Map<K,V> map = new TreeMap<K,V>();
    for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : c.entrySet()) {
        Object key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        map.put(clazz1.cast(key), clazz2.cast(value));
    }
    return map;
}
```

*Goodnews*: This time I did not get any error when I modified the initial code to call this method:

```
Map<String, MyDataBean> allTransactions = MyUtilityClass.castToMap(String.class, 
                                                               MyDataBean.class, 
            (Map<?,?>)pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("allTransactions"));
```

But I still had to cast it **^^^here** to call my function.

**Question 1:**
Why it does not show any errors now when I am still using the cast `(Map<?,?>)` versus what I tried before `(TreeMap<String,MyDataBean>)`?

**Question 2:**
My app is broken as of now since other developers have not committed the code yet, and so I am in no position to run the App and verify its correctness. Can anyone tell just by looking at it, if this casting will behave the same way as before?

Comment: I see no point in adding that method.  It accomplishes nothing concrete.  A Map is a Map and the generic notation is just window dressing -- useful as a debugging aid perhaps when writing new code but it just gets in the way when you know the code works as it.

Comment: Note that `TreeMap` has a constructor that takes a map. So your cast can simply be `return new TreeMap<K,V>(c);` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Map)

Comment: @HotLicks I had to get rid of the warnings. Could you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: @corsiKa That still gives unchecked warnings when I put it like this `return new TreeMap<K,V>((Comparator<? super K>) c);`

Comment: What's wrong with the original code?  Or `TreeMap<?,?>`?

Comment: @HotLicks the original code `TreeMap` gives unchecked warnings and `TreeMap<?,?>` gives a type mismatch error.

Comment: `TreeMap<?,?>` works fine for me.  Of course you need to make both the declaration and the cast have that form.

Comment: Or you can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")' as a qualifier on the method header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `Map` then it is implicitly a `Map<?,?>` - as in, a map of anything. It considers that to be a safe cast because, since it is a map, it cannot fail. At this point, it's no different than casting it to any other object, which they're assuming is safe.

If it is a bad cast (say it's a List, not a Map) then it will explode there before anything else goes wrong. But because those types are lost at compile time, it will happily continue if the problem is in the generic types. So `Map<?,?>` is considered safe because it will explode because of being not being a Map if that's the problem.

As far as your second issue, it looks fine, but without more context it's hard to say. That being said, you should be able to use the history in your source control to grab an earlier version to compare against. If you can't obtain earlier versions of your code, your source control isn't very useful, now is it?

Comment: If `it` is a Map then it is implicitly a Map<?,?> - you mean the session object?

Comment: No, I mean `pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("allTransactions")` - that's what you're casting after all, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am casting. But then what was wrong with `TreeMap<String,MyDataBean>`? I am more clear in my types here.

Comment: Because the session object doesn't store `TreeMap<String,MyDataBean>` references - it stores `Object` references. If you want to cast that `Object` to a `Map<?,?>` that's fine without a warning. But as soon as you try to throw those generic types in there, it says "wait, you need some validation around this."

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1.: The cast itself is safe, because you don't specify any types which the compiler can not match against the method signature. Java 4 `List` can be safely assigned to Java 5 `List<?>`, but when you specify a type, you assume something, the compile can not safely check (therefore the warning).

Ad 2.: You have substituted a "hard" language cast with a "soft" method call cast, which will fail equally, if the classes are not castable into one another - I prefer the less verbose version of language casting, because one should rely one one's API.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `hard` language cast. Could you please explain your `Ad2` explanation in simple terms?

Comment: I believe he means that a hard cast has the generic types defined, while a soft cast simply changes the reference type (not, of course, the underlying class type).

Comment: `TreeMap<String, MyDataBean> allTransactions = (TreeMap<String, MyDataBean>) pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("allTransactions");` is a language cast, because you use Java language constructs to cast the result of `getAttribute()` whilst `clazz1.cast(key)` uses a cast encapsulated in a method call.

Comment: A small nitpick, pre-generics was called Java 1.4, not Java 4. They dropped the "1." starting with Java 5.

Comment: Can you give an example of less verbose language casting in this context?

Comment: You already mentioned the cast producing a compiler warning - this one would be my choice. It is possible to suppress the compiler warning by annotating the casting statement with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` - but only use this, if you know what you're doing! ;-)